# Why is the text being transparent?

Tags: html, css

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Cool Effect</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="imageHolder">
        <span class="note">Hello!</span>
        <img src="picture1.jpeg">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.imageHolder {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
}

.note {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border: 2px solid white;
    padding: 8px;
    color: white;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
}

img {
    width: 300;
    opacity: 0.4;
    height: 250px;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xsqosw0c/1/

The text in the span appears to be slightly transparent, instead of a solid white. I'm not sure why this is happening. It is more clear if you make the font-size larger.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the text is behind the image. Use `z-index` to fix this:

```
.note {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border: 2px solid white;
    padding: 8px;
    color: white;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 24px;
    display: inline-block;

    z-index:2000;
}
```

`z-index` moves an element forward or backward into the CSS "layers". By default, the HTML elements will be "layered" in the order that they are shown in the HTML code. You can either re-order your HTML lines, or apply `z-index`

Answer (score 2):

its because your img was over that text

```
<div class="imageHolder">
    <img src="https://portthemedemo.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/bike.jpg?w=317&h=239&crop=1">
    <span class="note">Hello!</span>
</div>
```